# Can i embed another webpage from a non internet facing webserver with iframe

Tags: php, html, networking, iframe, amazon-ec2

I have a webserver in AWS that has a public IP (WEB01) and is fully accessble over the internet. WEB01 has a local connection to my VCP (Virtual private cloud) network. I have a second webserver (WEB02) at home with a VPN into my VCP. My security groups in AWS are setup and as a troubleshooting test I opened up all ports to all IPs
Both WEB01 and WEB02 can communicate with each other without issue. WEB01 can ping WEB02 and vica versa, and all looks good so far.

A Webpage on WEB01 calls a webpage on WEB02 with a simple iframe

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.2.15:8123" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

But is does not display and times out eventually.

I tested this as a proof of concept on Azure and thought it worked without issue, but now im questioning whether I ever connected to WEB01 without being on the same LAN as WEB02.

Im starting to suspect that iframe is called at the client side (end user), who has no access to the 192.168.2.0/24 network.
If my assumtion is correct then how can I get around this issue?

Comment: No, if it is not publicly accessible an iframe isn't going to help.  You need a Reverse Proxy but that will intern make the page public.

Comment: The page on WEB01 is publicly available as it should be. If I implement a reverse proxy, will it make WEB02 accessible from the internet.

Comment: Anything public can be displayed on WEB01.  If you want to display information on WEB01 from WEB02, you can enable a reverse proxy or manually proxy (via php).  This will make part or all of WEB02 publicly available, but with some control over what content is exposed.  If you need to do something like auth the user before displaying the content from WEB02 on WEB01, just use PHP and something like the Guzzle library to request, then forward the content from WEB02.  If the content is HTML, you are going to have to make sure other resources (imgs, css, js, etc) are available on or from WEB01.

Comment: Thats great. Investigating apache (httpd) now. 

Thank you for taking the time to reply